# Confirming $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+x)}{k^2k!}=-\frac{(H_{-x})^2+H^{(2)}_{-x}}2\Gamma(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I managed to show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+x)}{k^2k!}=-\frac{(H_{-x})^2+H^{(2)}_{-x}}2\Gamma(x)$$
(where $H^{(r)}_n$ are generalized harmonic numbers) but it doesn't seem to work for certain $x$ like $1/3$ and $1/5$, even though $2/3$ and $3/5$ do work. For know I've assumed that it works *best* for $x\geq1/2$. Another possibility is that Wolfram Alpha and Desmos are wrong, but since they agree with some of my answers and not others and are also two different calculators I'm not certain.

To prove it I used partial fractions and
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+x)}{(k+\lambda)k!}=\frac{\pi\Gamma(\lambda)}{\sin(\pi x)\Gamma(\lambda-x)}$$
to get $(k+\lambda)(k+\xi)$ in the denominator, then let $\xi\rightarrow\lambda$ and finally $\lambda\rightarrow0$ in a large limit, yielding the result in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to compute the partial sums. Before any simplification, if
$$S_p=\sum_{k=1}^p \frac{\Gamma(k+x)}{k^2\,k!}$$
$$S_p=-\frac{\Gamma (x)}{12}\left(6 \psi ^{(0)}(1-x)^2+12 \gamma  \psi ^{(0)}(1-x)-6 \psi ^{(1)}(1-x)+\pi
   ^2+6 \gamma ^2\right)-$$ $$\Gamma (p+1)^2 \Gamma (p+x+1) \, _4\tilde{F}_3(1,p+1,p+1,p+x+1;p+2,p+2,p+2;1)$$ and, when $p$ increases, the last term tends to $0$. So, simplifying the digamma function,as you probably did,
$$S_\infty=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+x)}{k^2\,k!}=-\frac{1}{12} \Gamma (x) \left(6 \left(H_{-x}\right){}^2-6 \psi ^{(1)}(1-x)+\pi
   ^2\right)$$ which is the same as your formula.

This has been checked numerically without any problem.